# Amazon EC2 (Tokyo) Can't Access Amazon RDS (Frankfurt)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have EC2 instance in Tokyo :

[image]

and I also have RDS instance in Frankfurt :

[image]

EC2's IP address already listed in RDS security groups :

[image]

But why EC2 Tokyo still unable to connect to RDS Frankfurt?

[image]

UPDATE : I changed 'Publicly accessible' option into 'Yes' as suggested, but the result still same.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database instance is set to not publicly accessible.

And, your RDS security group is not specifying the public IP of the EC2 instance. Instead you used the private IP address.

It’s important to understand that two different AWS sites can not communicate internally, unless you enable some type of VPN or peering.

All communications between the two instances happens over the public, unencrypted internet.

That means your DB has to be publicly accessible and your security group has to allow the public IP address of the EC2 instance.

In addition, your EC2 instance does not have an elastic IP assigned so it’s IP address is going to change randomly. Which is going to break your connection in the future when it does.

Comment: how to make it accessible?

Comment: Change the option. Click modify on the same screen you showed in your question.

Comment: I see... modifying now...

Comment: I changed, bro. check my update above. but I still can't login from Tokyo.

Comment: @SaintRobson see my updates.

Comment: It WORKS, bro... thank you so much for your help...